# two dropdowns connected using PHP, AJAX, Javascript and postgresql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have my index.php file which load all the countries correctly as seen in this image:

[image]

Also this is what I've seen in the first load:

[image]

```
<div class="content">
<?php
include("config.php");
?>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="country" id="country"> 
          <option value="">Select Country</option>
        <?php
       $db = pg_connect("$db_host $db_name $db_username $db_password");
       $query = "SELECT country FROM countries";

       $result = pg_query($query);
        if (!$result) {
            echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>";
          echo pg_last_error();
            exit();
      }

         while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            printf ("<option value=$myrow[country_id]>$myrow[country]</option>");
    }
         ?>
</select>
    <br>

<select name="state" id="state">
        <option value="">Select State</option>
</select>
    <br>

<select name="city" id="city">
        <option value="">Select City</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#country').on('change',function(){
    var countryID = $(this).val();
    if(countryID){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajaxData.php',
            data:'country_id='+countryID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#state').html(html);
                $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>');  
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#state').html('<option value="">Select country first</option>');
        $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
    }
});

$('#state').on('change',function(){
    var stateID = $(this).val();
    if(stateID){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajaxData.php',
            data:'state_id='+stateID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#city').html(html);
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Then I have the ajaxData.php file as below:

```
<?php
//Include database configuration file
include("config.php");

if(isset($_POST["country_id"]) && !empty($_POST["country_id"])){
//Get all state data
$query = "SELECT state FROM states WHERE country = ".$_POST['country_id'];

$result = pg_query($query);
        if (!$result) {
            echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>";
          echo pg_last_error();
            exit();
      }

//Count total number of rows
$get_total_rows = pg_numrows($results); 

//Display states list
if($get_total_rows > 0){
    echo '<option value="">Select state</option>';
    while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        echo '<option value="'.$myrow['state_id'].'">'.$myrow['state'].'</option>';
    }
}else{
    echo '<option value="">State not available</option>';
}

}
```

Once I select the country I see the following:

[image]

Since the text in the selectors has changed from "Select a State" to "Select country first", it seams that in my javascript funtion when $('#country').on('change',function()  is getting into

```
else{
        $('#state').html('<option value="">Select country first</option>');
        $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>');
```

Instead of going through:

```
    if(countryID){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajaxData.php',
            data:'country_id='+countryID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#state').html(html);
                $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>');  
            }
        });
```

There is obviously something that is not working but I'm not able to see what it is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can set a breakpoint on `if(countryID){` to see what the value is at that point, and why it's not going into the correct condition.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Sorry for my illiteracy but how do I set a breakpoint? I don't have a debugger. Thanks

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging is a good reference to start (if you're using Chrome).  Other browsers have similar tools.  Start by pressing `F12` or right clicking the page and then clicking "Inspect" - these will both open Developer Tools.  From there you can go to Sources, find the page/file your script is on, and debugging from there.